# Is an Ethiopian and Bedouin unity possible in a subaltern utopia for Palestine-Israel?

Tags: reference-request, racism, privilege

I would like to ask for a potential utopian scenario where Ethiopian Jews and LC(lower class) bedouins form some subaltern allegiance to combat the racism they face in Palestine-Israel. Is this possible? Any possible predictions or analysis of how such a scenario may arise? We know how misrahi Jews did their way of resisting the white-hegemony of Ashkenazis in Israel via [blackpanther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panthers_(Israel)) movement etc.

What homework I have done regarding understanding this problem? I recently read an Israeli bedoin(identity matters here) Professor's work which talks about the Ethiopian struggles. Link: https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/edit/10.4324/9780429281013-28/ethiopian-jews-israel-sarab-abu-rabia-queder

I think there are class hierarchies among bedoins too, although this is just a guess. Bedouins themselves are a diverse group of people as I understand. But in my understanding, ethiopian jews are a single group, at least in the Israeli context.

Was there anyone who put forward this idea of LC(lower class) unification? Or, if not, is such a scenario possible? Can we call it a subaltern resistance if it happens? Can we invoke Ambedkar's ideas here in Levant?

Comment: Maybe this would fit more on a politics or law SE?

Comment: @KristianBerryCan I move it smoothly to there? Any easy way?

Comment: Click "Edit" on your post here. Fix the text cursor in the post, press CRTL-A then CTRL-C. Go to https://politics.stackexchange.com/, make a new post there, and CTRL-V your post content from here to there.

Comment: I mean, there might be a way to make the post more philosophical, too, but for now it seems like a conjecture about a fairly specific context. EDIT: https://law.stackexchange.com/ is another option, maybe. I wish there was a sociology SE; through a Google search, it appears that sociology questions tend to get redirected to PhilosophySE or PsychologySE.

Comment: A specific problem has been presented with philosophical implications. It all boils down to *irrationality* of some sort although I can't rule out *hidden wisdom*. It's quite inexplicable, this, given information is just a mouse-click away.

Comment: +1 Also if I personally agree that the question is for Politic, the question itself is interesting and worthy to be read. Having said that, IMO it is difficult to imagine how "a potential utopian scenario" will fit into current socio-political reality.